# how do you use the terminal on mac os 10 to write and compile c++ code?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

how do you use the terminal on mac os 10 to write and compile c++ code?
I have a power mac with the power pc chip/with leopard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, make sure you've got [Apple's developer tools](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/) installed. They may be on your Mac OS X install disk as well, if you don't feel like downloading. (although you may get an older version) After that, `cd` to where your code is and do something similar to this:

```
g++ -o my_executable my_cpp_code.cpp
```

You can then run it like this:

```
./my_executable
```

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that the installation of the compiler tools under /usr/bin is _optional_ in Xcode’s installer, so be sure to select that.

Comment: @icktoofay Hi, I just started to learn c++ with some knowledge of python. Just a few questions. In python, to run a script you would just do `python script.py`. In C++, it seems you do what you posted. But what is `my_executable`? I'm rather new to computer languages. One last question, when doing my hello world script, it doesn't seem to do a linebreak. I tried adding `\n` but it didn't work. How do I fix that? Thanks :)

Comment: @Haidro: With Python, your code is run by the Python interpreter, usually with the name `python`. When you use native, compiled languages, there is no interpreter; your program *is* the executable. Rather than using `python script.py`, you would use just `./program`. (A Python 'equivalent' (though it's still interpreted) would be adding an appropriate hashbang at the top and setting the executable bit on the script's permissions. Then you use `./script.py` just as if it were a native executable.)

Comment: @Haidro: As for newlines, `\n` should work just fine. I don't know why it's not working for you. Perhaps start a new question, including your code, how you're compiling it, and how you're running it.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest text editor included with Mac is `nano`. It's pretty self-explanatory. Once you've saved the source file, just run `g++ my_source_file.cpp -o my_program_name` to compile.

However, I recommend using the XCode IDE. The old version 3.2 is a 600 MB download, or the new 4.0 is $5. Even though it's not the best, you will have a much better time with it than learning the command line from scratch. And if you install the compiler using Apple's installer in the first place, you already have it.